# Dart: declaration behavior of function parameters is different from declaration behavior of local variables

Tags: dart

I have this simple function:

```
void fooFun(int i1, j1) {
  int i2, j2;
  print('${i1.runtimeType}, ${j1.runtimeType}');
}
```

I would assume that the declared type of the function parameter `j1` is `int`. But when I hover with the mouse cursor over `j1` it is displayed as dynamic:
[image: Type of function parameter]
But `j1.runtimeType` is (as expected?) an`int`.
When I declare two variables in the same manner locally (`int i2, j2;`), the declaration type of the second variable `j2` is as expected  `int`.
[image: local variable declaration]

This seems a little bit confusing to me:

- Why is the declaration type of `j1` `dynamic` and not `int`?
- Why is the runtime Type different from the declared type? (`j1.runtimeType` is `int` and not `dynamic`)?
- Why is the "declaration behavior" of a function parameter list different from locally declared variables?

By the way: I use VSCode as IDE.
I have bundled the three questions above into one post because i think they are very closely related.

Comment: Why would you assume that the type just cascades over?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore : So when declaring variables locally the type cascades over, but when declared as function parameters the type does not cascade over? Seems a little bit insconsistent for me, but ok.

Comment: It cascades for lists on the same line. Never for function definitions. This has been a standard for decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter declarations and variable declarations are different, they do not work the same.

Variable declarations are terminated by `;`. One variable declaration can declare multiple variables like `int i, j;`. That's a syntax inherited back (at least) from the C language, and also allowed by Java, C# and JavaScript, the three languages Dart was most inspired by in the beginning.

A parameter declaration is not terminated, but parameter declarations are separated by commas, as a comma separated list. Because of that, it can't also use commas to declare multiple variables in one declaration, so you need to write two declarations, `(int i, int j)`, to declare two parameters. Again, this behavior is (at least) as old as C, and shared by both Java and C# (JavaScript doesn't type variables at all).
If you write `(int i, j)` that is still two separate parameter declarations, the second just defaults to `dynamic` as type, as if you had written `(int i, dynamic j)`. Other languages may or may not allow you to omit the type.

The declaration defines the type of the *variable*, which restricts the values which it can contain.
Using `.runtimeType` provides the type of a *value*, not a *variable*.
The `dynamic j` variable can contain an integer value, so printing `j.runtimeType` does not tell you anything about the *variable's* type.

You can also do `print([j].runtimeType);` which will print `List<dynamic>`, telling you that the *static*/declared type of `j` is `dynamic`.
(Or declare `void logType<T>(T value) { print(T); }` and call `logType(j);`, then type inference will make it `logType<dynamic>(j)` because the static type of `j` is `dynamic`, and it will print "dynamic".)

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration should be: `int i1, int j1`, because `int i1, j1` is interpreted like this `int i1, dynamic j1`

`runtimeType` method tries to *discover* the data type of that object according its data.